# Storing a range of values in a Double type array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have two columns of interest in a table of medical side effects, the names of the side effects and their severity from 0.10 - 25.00 as a decimal number. Using a string array and transpose, I store the first column of text without an issue, but trying to fill the double array the same way fails with a Type Mismatch error. Why is this the case? I am able to bypass this by using a variant array, but when I fill the variant array all of the individual indexes are of type Double. I've tried using CDbl and a # to force the issue, but  that won't work either. The range only covers the data, not the headers.

```
Function DiagnoseSideEffect(ByRef rngSide As Range) As String
    Dim sSideFx() As Variant
    Dim dSeverity() As Double
    Dim vSeverity() As Variant
    ' ... Other declarations

    sSideFx = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngSide.Columns(2).Value)
    dSeverity = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngSide.Columns(4).Value) ' ERROR: Type Mismatch
    vSeverity = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngSide.Columns(4).Value) ' Works fine
    ' Rest of function...
End Function
```

Comment: It indeed is the case, only thing I noticed is that they are "Variant/Double" and maybe that is the reason for Type Mismatch. The only way I could load up Double array was by looping each element.

Comment: That's because Range.Value _Returns or sets a Variant value that represents the value of the specified range._, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)

Comment: Where exactly is this *"Using a string array and transpose, I store the first column of text without an issue"* happening since you have `Dim sSideFx() As Variant`? You can only use *Variant* arrays with these single-liners. Be aware that they will fail anyway if `rngSide` happens to be a single row or doesn't have enough columns. Showing the rest of the function would make it easier to present a good way to handle this case i.e. to decide whether using *String* or *Double* typed arrays, or even transposing makes sense.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - You're right, I didn't catch that.  Mental slip.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to use Worksheetfunction.Transpose to get the result.

The reason of the **Type Mismatch error** comes from the Transpose Method.
The Transpose will transpose only the amount of cells from a column which in principal could be pasted in a line as a result of the method. Doesn't matter that you assign it to a variable.

```
Dim myarr as Variant
myarr = Columns(7).Value
```

gives a two dimensional array myarr(x,y) starting indices with 1.

Items can get with

```
myarr(item,1)
```

In general it is worth to get the last item of a range not to take unnecessary data

With this can get a one dimensional array with type Double

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
ReDim arr(lastRow - 1) As Double
For i = 0 To lastRow - 1
arr(i) = Cells(i + 1, 7)
Next i
```

In your code

```
ReDim dSeverity(rngSide.Rows.Count) As Double
For i = 0 To rngSide.Rows.Count - 1
dSeverity(i) = rngSide(i + 1, 4)
Next i
```